# Delete a few selected days data from a Data of 3 months in R

Tags: r, datetime

I have 4 months data like

```
2020-04-01 06:01:00 
2020-04-01 06:02:00 
2020-04-01 06:03:00
..
..
2020-07-31 19:12:00 
2020-07-31 19:13:00 
2020-07-31 19:14:00 
2020-07-31 19:15:00
```

I have to delete a few selected days data like 7 April, 4 June, 6 July data in between this data frame in R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a vector of dates that you want to delete and remove those dates from the data. Suppose your column is called `datetime` and dataframe is called `df` you can do :

```
delete_dates <- as.Date(c('2020-04-07', '2020-06-04', '2020-07-06'))
new_data <- subset(df, !as.Date(datetime) %in% delete_dates)
```

Also confirm that `datetime` column is of class `POSIXct`, if it is not you need to first change the class by using `as.POSIXct`.

```
df$datetime <- as.POSIXct(df$datetime, tz = 'UTC')
```

Answer (score 0):

An option with `filter`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
      filter(!as.Date(datetime) %in% delete_dates)
```

#### data

```
delete_dates <- as.Date(c('2020-04-07', '2020-06-04', '2020-07-06'))
```